# how to prevent node express with handlebars to reload page

Tags: express, handlebars.js, structure

I am building a website with node js currently and wanted to render the pages with handlebarjs. The website has a navbar, the links in the navbar are routes in my node application.
My problem is that the hole website with navbar get reload. Is there any way to prevent this.

If not would it be the best practise to split website and node in separate dictionaries and make request to the server and response the data in json?

Comment: What do you mean the "whole website with navbar gets reloaded"?  Do you mean when you click on a navbar link, the whole page is reloaded?  If so, this would be normal and typical for most web sites.  You'd have to either build what is sometimes called a single-page-app that loads content with Javascript or use frames in order to only load part of the page and then the URL of the page would typically not change when you navigated.  It's unclear what problem you're really trying to solve or how you want it to work.

Comment: On a simple html js css webpage the navbar etc is normally cached, it appears to not be reloading. On my current solution the hole page get reloaded (takes way longer)

Comment: We can't really help much without seeing your actual HTML for the whole page and understanding what problem you're trying to solve.  If the navbar is part of the same HTML page as the rest of your HTML (no frames), then the browser can't cache it independently.  The browser will be asking for the page URL and the server will be providing the HTML for the entire page.  There is no sub-page HTML caching in the browser.  I wonder if the format of your HTML is causing a rendering hitch when the page is displayed and that's what you're seeing.